# odoo:get unit price from an other table

Tags: python, odoo

I want the price to be automatically displayed when I select the product in the invoice

```
@api.one
@api.depends('price_unit')
def _on_change_service (self):
    self.price_unit = self.le_prix
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually just finished something similar.
I did it using `@api.onchange` so for your purpose the function can look like this:

`@api.onchange('product')
def product_changed(self)
    self.price = self.product.price`

In the view just display the fields.

Comment: Yes it will work, just pay attention to the elements you are involving.
As I can see, your invoice table has a relation to service table, so you need to add the `onchange` method in the invoice class for the `service` field. (In the example I gave you replace product by service)

Comment: thats exactly what i did but it dosnt work                               this is my code  @api.onchange('services')
    def _on_change_service (self):
     self.price_unit = self.services.le_prix

Comment: this is the error :AttributeError: 'lignes.de.facture' object has no attribute 'services'